# Hausman Test interpretation is based on the p-value? - R output

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, hausman

I obtained the following output after running the Hausman test:

1) CASE 1 Hausman Test chisq = 13.943, df = 4, p-value = 0.007478 alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent

2) CASE 2 Hausman Test chisq = 0.49157, df = 4, p-value = 0.9743 alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent

According to the p-values and for significance <0.05, should I go for the fixed effects in CASE 1 and for the random effects in CASE 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See the following taken from a Princeton slide:

> To decide between fixed or random effects you can run a Hausman test
>   where the null hypothesis is that the preferred model is random
>   effects vs. the alternative the fixed effects (see Green, 2008,
>   chapter 9). It basically tests whether the unique errors (ui) are
>   correlated with the regressors, the null hypothesis is they are not.
>   Run a fixed effects model and save the estimates, then run a random
>   model and save the estimates, then perform the test. If the p-value is
>   significant (for example <0.05) then use fixed effects, if not use
>   random effects.

see: https://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101R.pdf

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore :)